# Rebind CapsLock to a different key?

Tags: key-bindings

Is it possible to rebind the <kbd>Capslock</kbd> key to something else?

For example, suppose we want to invoke the <kbd>Control-x</kbd> commands by using <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>; so instead of pressing <kbd>Control-x</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>, one can type <kbd>Capslock</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>.

Comment: You could try combing this http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CapsKey#toc5 with what you have already tried.

Comment: Capslock is a special key, and you will need to remap it at the operating system level before you can use it for this task in Emacs.  Many Vim (and Evil) users rebind it to escape, and many standard Emacs users rebind it to Control.  You can probably adapt those efforts for your purposes.  Each operating system will do it differently, however, so look for yours (and probably edit your post to tell us which one you're using).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User [Dan](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/253/dan) mentions: *"<kbd>Capslock</kbd> is a special key, and you will need to remap it at the operating system level before you can use it for this task in Emacs."*  ([Source](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19269/rebind-capslock-to-a-different-key#comment29242_19269))

<kbd>Capslock</kbd> was first re-mapped to Nabla (∇). This was done at the Operating System level; [Example](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CapsKey#toc5) configuration.

Now, the desired task can be achieved by re-mapping Nabla from within Emacs. For example, to map Nabla to `Control-X-prefix`, the following command can be used:

`(global-set-key '[8711] 'Control-X-prefix)`